# ADO.NET proper INSERT of data

Tags: c#, insert, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I am using a SQL CE 3.5 database in my C# project.

When I am adding new data to a table, let's say a simple row, I feel like I am doing it totally wrong. What I am doing is something like this:

```
const string commandStr = "INSERT INTO tableName (size, x, y) VALUES(@size, @x, @y)";
using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(commandStr, _connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", size);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", y);
    int affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Of course, my actual table that I am using in my project has a lot more collumns. Obviously, this is a lot of typing.
This brings me to the point where I am thinking: "I am a .NET devoloper. There must be something that feels a lot more naturally."

So my questions are:
Is there a nicer way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes there are edge cases where doing it your way is required. However, for a full, verbose, ".NET developer" feel, try Entity Framework. It is awesome.

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) is so nice for this in my opinion. I really enjoy using it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's called Linq :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx

Linq 2 SQL or Linq 2 Entities, depending on your specific needs. I find it more natural than using raw ado.net and I bet you won't feel any real performance problems.

Comment: I didn't know that LINQ can be linked up to a database. Thank you, I'll try that!